# Physical mem used % and Physical Vcores Used % in spark 3 yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, dataproc

I like to understand,what is "Physical mem used % and Physical Vcores Used %" in spark 3 yarn.
I don't see these metric in spark 2.4 and i could see these new metric in spark 3 yarn.

What is Physical mem used % ?
What is Physical Vcores Used %?

Even cluster 100% I could see Physical mem used 48% and Physical Vcore used 86%

Please help to understand the logic behind these metrics